# Passing an anonymous function as an argument but it treats it as a string

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript/programming and I was playing around with passing functions as arguments just to get familiar with the concept. I saw the following example online and tried to create my own more simple example:

```
var materialsLength1 = materials.map(function(material) {
   return material.length;
});
```

Here's what I tried:

```js
function appendLetterToString(letter, str) {
    return str += letter
}

let pizza = appendLetterToString("a", function(){
    return "pizz";
})

console.log(pizza);
```

I was expecting to get 'pizza' in the console but the result I got is this string:

```
function(){
    return "pizz";
}a
```

Why does my 'function' get evaluated as a string?
Hope this isn't a dumb question. Appreciate any answers!

Comment: `return str() + letter`

Comment: `function appendLetterToString(letter, func) { let text = func(); return text += letter;   }`

Comment: the only way to call an  anonymous function is to assign it to a variable and then calling it by that variable's name. and you are not doing that

Comment: You can pass functions around, yes, but they won't magically execute "at the right time". If you pass a function into a function, that receiving function must understand that its argument is a function and treat it as such. You can't just treat it like a string and expect the right thing to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does my 'function' get evaluated as a string?

Because you don't run the function, so the value isn't `pizz`, but the function itself, as a string.

---

In your example there is no need to pass the second arg as a function, but if you want that, you should call it to get it's return value:

```js
function appendLetterToString(letter, str) {
    return str() + letter
}

let pizza = appendLetterToString("a", function(){
    return "pizz";
})

console.log(pizza);
```

---

But you're probably better of passing a string:

```js
function appendLetterToString(letter, str) {
    return str += letter
}

let pizza = appendLetterToString("a", "pizz");

console.log(pizza);
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see what I did wrong there. But I'm still curious as to why it magically interprets it as a string rather than throwing an error?

Comment: Since you are using `+`, the value is getting parsed to a string, therefore there is no error, since thats fine by JS. Same goes for `true + 1`, `true` get's evaluated to string, `1` and `1 + 1` is `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous functions work the same as named functions: you have to call them explicitly; they don't get called automatically when used in expressions.

So if you want a method to accept an anonymous function as an argument, you have to write the code inside the method to call the function.

For example, if you want `str` to be a function, you could write the append function like this:

```
function appendLetterToString(letter, str) {
  return str() += letter
}
```

Now it will work *only* if you pass a function, not if you pass a string. If you want it to work both ways, you have to examine the type of the value inside the body:

```
function appendLetterToString(letter, strOrFun) {
    let str = strOrFun
    if (typeof strOrFun === 'function')
        str = strOrFun()
    return str += letter
}
```